# How can I get the name of a file in a directory on unix based on grep, sed, or awk in unix or linux?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

How can I get the name of a file in a directory on unix based on sed, grep, or awk in unix or linux?

I though I could do something like:

```
    for i in $(ls /tmp/files/date*); do
       if [ $(cat $i | head -n 1 | grep -c "6") >= 1 ] ; then
          echo $i
       fi
    done
```

I need it to search all of the files in a certain directory (only the first line in them each) and then return which files have the string in them.

Thanks, 
  Tim

Comment: don't parse `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Don't use `ls`, the glob itself is enough (and not prone to whitespace/ugly character problems as `ls` is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your script a little bit and get the desired result:

```
for i in /tmp/files/date*; do
   if head -n 1 "$i" | grep -q "6"; then
      basename "$i"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems in your code. I'll go through them more or less in order of importance.

1. You're missing `then`:
   `if [ $(cat $i | head -n 1 | grep -c "6" >= 1) ] ; then`
2. Don't parse `ls`, the glob is enough:
   `for i in /tmp/files/date*; do`
3. The `>=` should be outside the subshell:
   `if [ $(cat $i | head -n 1 | grep -c "6") >= 1 ] ; then`
4. The `>=` should be `-ge` to compare numerically:
   `if [ $(cat $i | head -n 1 | grep -c "6") -ge 1 ] ; then`
5. Quote `"$i"` and the subshell, you don't need to quote 6:
   `if [ "$(cat "$i" | head -n 1 | grep -c 6)" -ge 1 ] ; then`
6. The return value of `grep` can be used to control the `if` (switch `-c` to `-q` because you want it quiet and you don't need a count:
   `if cat "$i" | head -n 1 | grep -q 6 ; then`
7. You don't need cat here:
   `if head -n 1 "$i" | grep -q 6 ; then`

So:

```
for i in /tmp/files/date*; do
   if head -n 1 "$i" | grep -q 6 ; then
      echo $i
   fi
done
```

Depending on what you're going to be doing with the list, you may want to go about it a different way (`find`, probably).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename` to get the last part of a path (the filename)

```
$ basename '/usr/bin/env'
env
```

Answer (score 0):

"I need it to search all of the files in a certain directory (only the first line in them each) and then return which files have the string in them."

A combination of find, grep ,cut

```
find a_certain_directory_name -exec \grep -n -H -m 1 my_search_string {} \; | cut -f 1,2 -d : | grep -e ":1\$" | cut -f 1 -d :
```